# TabLayout wont populate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm starting with some Design support Library resources, specifically the TabLayout.

It's a simple snippet, but I'm not able to populate my TabLayout, the Fragments are sliding normally but my TabLayout is not getting populatad with the Titles as we can see in the attached picture.
I'm not sure if I should wrap ViewPager inside a fragment together with the TabLayout, it just make sense to me.

Follow, thanks.

http://postimg.org/image/x1z6zvlqd/

Main fragment Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_sliding_tabs_about"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_about_fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main fragment java

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vp_about_fragment_content);
        mAdapter = new AboutPageAdapter(getFragmentManager(),
                getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_sliding_tabs_about);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }
```

Page Adapter java

```
public class AboutPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final   int    PAGE_COUNT  = 2;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"Tab A", "Tab B"};
    private Context context;

    public AboutPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return FragA.newInstance(position);
            default:
                return FragB.newInstance(position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call  `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` in `onViewCreated()` method?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski No success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your tips, I was able to make it work with:

```
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mTabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

"Official" Workaround:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180462#c17

```
if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(tabLayout)) {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    } else {
        tabLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

                tabLayout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            }
        });
    }
```